# Как в HTML растянуть фоновое изображение на всю страницу?

Tags: html

Как в php растянуть фоновое изображение на всю страницу?

Comment: А причем тут php? Php только отдает html, например, а дальше уже css в браузере действует.

Answer (score 2):

1. Откладываете PHP в сторону.
2. Учите CSS.
3. Растягиваете фоновое изображение на всю страницу.
4. Продолжаете учить PHP.